# How to install the guess_language package in Python

Tags: python

This question might be trivial but, honesty, I can't figure out as I am new to python.

I run Python 2.7.3 and the aforementioned package can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language)

I would really appreciate if you could help make sure that I have installed it correctly on my laptop. FYI here are the outputs of the commands ***$ ./setup.py install*** and ***$ python2 setup.py install*** respectively.

**$ ./setup.py install**

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/guess_language
copying guess_language/__main__.py -> build/lib/guess_language
copying guess_language/__init__.py -> build/lib/guess_language
copying guess_language/console_mode.py -> build/lib/guess_language
creating build/lib/guess_language/data
copying guess_language/data/__init__.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data
creating build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/az.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/tl.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/pt.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/hu.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/so.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/pt_br.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/da.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/tn.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/fr.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/fi.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/__init__.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/is.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/id.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/bg.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/la.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sl.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/pl.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ca.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ru.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sk.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/lt.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ne.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/af.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/haw.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sq.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/nl.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ceb.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/nso.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/en.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/uz.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/es.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ts.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/cs.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sw.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/mn.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ro.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/hi.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/tlh.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/lv.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/zu.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/vi.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ar.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ss.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/pt_pt.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/it.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/de.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ky.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sv.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ha.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/cy.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/xh.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/fa.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/kk.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/et.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/tr.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/st.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/sr.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ve.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ur.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/ps.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/nb.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/eu.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/nr.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/uk.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/mk.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
copying guess_language/data/models/hr.py -> build/lib/guess_language/data/models
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/guess_language_spirit-0.5a3.egg-info
error: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/guess_language_spirit-0.5a3.egg-info: Permission denied
```

**$ python2 setup.py install**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 597, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "setup.py", line 592, in main
    run_setup_hooks(config)
  File "setup.py", line 569, in run_setup_hooks
    func(config)
  File "setup.py", line 582, in default_hook
    generate_py2k(config)
  File "setup.py", line 543, in generate_py2k
    run_3to2(copied_py_files)
  File "setup.py", line 374, in run_3to2
    raise OSError("3to2 script is unavailable.")
OSError: 3to2 script is unavailable.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `setup.py install` command as root:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Otherwise you won't have permission to copy the files to your `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages` directory.

To install the package on Python 2, you'll need to install the [`3to2` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2) first.

Comment: Instead of running as root, you can use a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: @Kos: Which, on Python 3.2, would require installing as root first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Although both packages installed successfully (at least it seems they did...), eclipse doesn't recognise the `from guess_language import guess_language` command... it says "unresolved import" any suggestion?

Comment: @MartijnPieters do providers offer python without virtualenv?

Comment: @Kos: I have no idea, and that has nothing to do with the OP question. This is a *laptop*.

Comment: @eualin: sorry, no idea. Does python code importing the module run?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't get it. Can you explain?

Comment: @eualin: Perhaps Eclipse can't find it, but if Python can it is still properly installed. Run `python` from the command line, and in the interactive prompt type `import guess_language`.

Comment: you are right. I tried this earlier but doesn't seems to work. so what should I guess??

Comment: @eualin: It looks like you have multiple python installations. Did you test with the correct one? You seem to be installing into the Python 3.2 installation, for example, so test with `python3.2`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right It works for python2. The strange thing however is that it doesn't work for `from guess_language import guess_language` as package’s tutorial states but it does work for `import guess_language` Any idea?

Comment: @eualin: Sorry, no, I am not familiar with the package. You can do a `dir(guess_language)` to see what *is* available and match that up with the documentation perhaps to get an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I can't get the hit. Where should I do `dir`??? Moreover, what about the classpath, I mean the place where the configuration of the PyDev plug-in (and all the dependences) is taking place....

Comment: @eualin: Python doesn't have a classpath; if PyDev does, then that's because it's written in Python (like the rest of Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

These days you can just use pip - the python package manager to install it:

1. You'll need to install pip - and then
2. simply: `pip install guess_language`