# language-check for python on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I tried to use

```
pip install --user --upgrade language-check
```

I then get the issue that is referenced here.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551969/how-to-install-the-guess-language-pachage-in-python
```

The solution is for a apple based, now windows, using sudo. I tried to open a command line as administrator and run the pip command but still the same issue. Some insight would be appreciated.

I ran

pip install --user --upgrade language-check

and then in response to command

```
Collecting language-check
  Using cached language-check-0.7.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: language-check
  Running setup.py install for language-check
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ryan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bn8yq0\\langu
age-check\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read
().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ryan\app
data\local\temp\pip-m78aoq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally
-managed --compile --user:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 597, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 592, in main
        run_setup_hooks(config)
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 562, in run_setup_hooks
        default_hook(config)
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 574, in default_hook
        generate_py2k(config)
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 542, in generate_py2k
        run_3to2(copied_py_files)
      File "c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0\language-check\set
up.py", line 375, in run_3to2
        raise OSError('3to2 script is unavailable.')
    OSError: 3to2 script is unavailable.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\ryan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bn8yq0\\language-check\\setup.py';exe
c(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-m78a
oq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --use
r" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bn8yq0
\language-check
```

Comment: Instead of referencing another issue, Please post the exact details of the issue here , what the error is, what command you ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error suggests, you need to install the 3to2 script first , First do -

```
pip install 3to2
```

Then run your command.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got over one hurdle. Im finding that Im getting this though when I try to import the library. I tried to import subprocess, but still running into an issue here. Any tips? 

>>> import subprocess
>>> import language_check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\langu
ck\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'

Comment: Hmm, seems like that is still python 3 code , can you try `pip install language-check --upgrade` again ?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>pip install language-check --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: language-check in c:\users\ryan\appdata\roaming\
python\python27\site-packages

Seems to be updated.

Comment: And still getting the issue?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question , I am not sure what would be going wrong.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for getting me over one of the walls.